# Is it safe to do something after "delete this" if the "somethings" does not require to access "this"?

Tags: c++, memory-management, undefined-behavior, retain-cycle

for example, I have a class which has a retain count and a release method that can delete self if the retain count is 0:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    void retain(){
        this->retainCount++;
    }

    void release(){
        this->retainCount--;
        if(this->retainCount==0){
            delete this;
        }

        printf("release called");
        MyClass::deleteCount++;
        FileOutputStream* fio=new FileOutputStream();
        fio->generateLog();
        delete fio;
        EmailUtils::sendEmailAboutMemoryUsage();
    }
protected:
    int retainCount;
    static int deleteCount;
}
```

Which I may have some code to do after the object is deleted:

```
printf("release called");
MyClass::deleteCount++;
FileOutputStream* fio=new FileOutputStream();
fio->generateLog();
delete fio;
EmailUtils::sendEmailAboutMemoryUsage();
```

My question is, if the code block after delete does not require any access of this, is it safe to continue the execution of code after the object is deleted?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?  Are you asking is it undefined behavior?  Or is it likely to blow up on a particular platform?

Comment: Sounds to me like the hidden answer is "use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: It is, and this is actually the approach that Microsoft's Component Object Model (COM) uses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's an entry of the isocpp FAQ about this issue.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this)

> As long as you’re careful, it’s okay (not evil) for an object to commit suicide (delete this).

Basically, if you're not calling any member function or accessing any member variable after `delete this`, it **may be** okay.

See the link for details.

Answer (score 6):

This is perfectly defined behaviour **provided you can be sure that your object had been allocated with `new`**.

In that case, it calls the destructor and releases memory associated with the object making `this` a dangling pointer. As you do not access it after the delete, there is no immediate problem in your code.

BUT you should at least add a strong notice in that method because even if safe, you should warn future maintainers of the two now unbreakable rules:

- do not access `this` nor any member variable of non static method after the `delete this`
- never create a non dynamically allocated object of that class

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe. The code is not removed when you delete `this`. But this is a strange thing to do. My rule of thump is: "whoever creates something, should destroy it". I don't like creating things (objects, arrays, ...) in a place (in the code) and destroying them elsewhere. This may lead to bugs and memory leaks, and makes your program less readable and maintainable.